# adding click events to a div's child div's, where the child div have a child a-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one `<div>`, where there's a lot of `<div>`s inside of it, and every child `<div>` gotta an `<a>`(anchor tag).

so what i'm trying to do is attach click events to the a-tags.
It's been working with a ul listed of mine divs. but i need it to be divs.

working code below:

**jQuery**:

```
$('#filterOptions li a').click(function (e) {});
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="filterOptions">
 <li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="prem">Premier League</a></li></li>
</ul>
```

An what I've tried which also didn't work is:

**jQuery**:

```
$('#filterOptions div a').click(function (e) {});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="filterOptions">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
      <a href="#" class="all">All</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="#" class="league2 ">Premier League>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help to me achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have class `filterOptions` in html markup and you are using id `#` in the jQuery code. It should be like:

```
$('.filterOptions div a').click(function (e) {});
```

Comment: .. can't believe i didn't see that. thanks, i have just try changing it. and it don't work. so yes. indeed it was a error with the id/class. but still not getting the a-tag child element.

Comment: As per you markup, the `a` tags don't have any child elements, it just have text which you can get by `$('a').text()`

Comment: sorry, what i mean is not the a-tag got a child element, but the a-tag itself is a child element, and it's the a-tag i wanna give a click event

Comment: @DaCh: Notting what you mean here. Could you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I just got what you mean, that the a is only text and not a child. i need to attach the click event to the child div instead. an that would work. so you are right, thanks for your help